# How to add "Code sample" under "Numbered list"?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, list

I want to add **Code sample** under **Numbered List** but unfortunately I am not able to do so.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:
Using *Numbered List* -

1. This is my first point
2. I want to add my code sample under this point

   public class HelloWorld {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println("Hello, World");
       }
   }
3. My Third point.

Without using *Numbered List* -

i. This is my first point
ii. I want to add my code sample under this point

```
public class HelloWorld {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        System.out.println("Hello, World");  
    }  
}
```

iii. My Third point.

I want my code sample should look like this. (Similar to the one Without using *Numbered List*)
How can I achieve this using **Numbered List**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply indent by 8 spaces<sup>1</sup>, like below:

1. This is my first point
2. I want to add my code sample under this point

   ```
   public class HelloWorld {  
     public static void main(String[] args) {  
       System.out.println("Hello, World");  
     }  
   }
   ```
3. My Third point.

Here's the Markdown:

```
1. This is my first point
2. I want to add my code sample under this point

        public class HelloWorld {  
          public static void main(String[] args) {  
            System.out.println("Hello, World");  
          }  
        }  
3. My Third point.
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Or, if already indented, an extra 4 spaces.